# How to customize priority of tax queries in wp query to show specific tax at the bottom

Tags: php, wordpress

I want to customize priority of taxonomy queries in Wordpress query to show specific taxonomy at the bottom and when other taxonomy contents finished.

for example I have category and tag taxonomies query and I want the query to display all category posts and at the end of category post display tag posts.

How to write the query to work like this.

I try `posts_tax_query filter` but I don't know how to customize it.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can achieve this custom sorting of taxonomy queries in WordPress by modifying the main SQL query using the posts_orderby filter. Here's how you can do it:

```
function custom_taxonomy_query_orderby($orderby, $query) {
    // Check if this is the main query and if we are on an archive page
    if ($query->is_main_query() && $query->is_archive()) {
        global $wpdb;

        // Define the taxonomies you want to prioritize and their respective terms
        $priority_taxonomy = 'category'; // Change this to your desired priority taxonomy
        $priority_terms = array(); // Add the IDs of terms you want to prioritize in the category taxonomy

        // If it's a category archive
        if ($query->is_category()) {
            // Move priority terms to the end
            $orderby = "FIELD({$wpdb->terms}.term_id, " . implode(',', $priority_terms) . ") DESC, " . $orderby;
        } elseif ($query->is_tag()) {
            // Move all category posts to the beginning
            $orderby = "IF( {$wpdb->term_taxonomy}.taxonomy = '{$priority_taxonomy}', 0, 1), " . $orderby;
        }
    }
    return $orderby;
}
add_filter('posts_orderby', 'custom_taxonomy_query_orderby', 10, 2);
```

This code snippet should be added to your theme's functions.php file or a custom plugin. Make sure to replace 'category' with the slug of your priority taxonomy and update $priority_terms array with the term IDs you want to prioritize.

This code does the following:

Checks if it's the main query and if it's an archive page.
For category archives, it moves posts from the priority terms to the end of the query results.
For tag archives, it moves posts from the priority taxonomy to the beginning of the query results.
Make sure to adjust it according to your specific taxonomy structure and requirements.